# Recursive Maltego local transforms

Tags: python, csv, graph

I'm trying to use the MaltegoTransform module to parse a csv file to a maltego graph.

Given that it is a transform which has to be applied on some kind of entity, I've defined it to accept any kind of entity as input.
Now for the fun part,
Each line within the csv is a domain and its referers and referees (in the form of a long string, each domain seperated with a |).

I want to be able to parse each said line into my graph in such a way that the structure remains, meaning that a domain would be pointed to (with edges) by his referers and point to his referees.
I aim to do this for each line within the csv.

So far, I wasn't able to create the structure I'm after due to the fact that each entity returned from the transform, gets an edge from the entity that called the transform, which as explained above, called be a random entity..

Any ideas?

Comment: you can create your own local transforms with the help of python and canari, canari allows you to declare the type of linklabel (link) that you want to use for your transform and the resulting entities

Answer (score 0):

**Short:** Transforms for Maltego (all at this stage) can only return entities that are child nodes of the entity the transform was run on as well as updating the transform they were run on (see http://dev.paterva.com/developer/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21).

But, since Maltego written in Java, you can try to write your own implementation of Entity and Link Factories (so they will create those elements in Maltego DB based on LocalTransform's XML output)